# Como usar ForEach em uma array multidimensional no PHP

Tags: php, array, foreach, array-multidimensional

Gostaria de saber como correr toda a array somente com ForEach:

```
$Marcas = array(array('Fiat', 'Volkswagen', 'Audi'),array('Yamaha', 'Suzuki', 'Honda'),array('Samsung', 'Motorola', 'Apple'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Um array multidimensional normalmente seria percorrido com um duplo `foreach`. No seu caso com:

```
foreach ($Marcas as $subMarcas){
    foreach ($subMarcas as $marca){
        //código aqui
    }
}
```

No entanto fiquei com a ideia que queria fazer algo apenas com um `foreach`. Consegue fazer isso se obtiver um array em que corresponda à junção de todos os sub-arrays.

Para isso pode utilizar [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.call-user-func-array.php) passando como primeiro parâmetro `"array_merge"` e como segundo o array de marcas, e depois é só iterar normalmente:

```
$marcas = call_user_func_array("array_merge", $Marcas);
foreach ($marcas as $marca){
    //código aqui
}
```

Até pode fazer numa linha śo se quiser:

```
foreach (call_user_func_array("array_merge", $Marcas) as $marca){
    //código aqui
}
```

[Veja este último exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/p3VjDl)